# How do I set up page caching in html?

Tags: http, caching, html, page-caching

The site has been coded by me from scratch. **Not** a wordpress site. I ran a site audit and naturally theres a lot to be done; one of which is **page caching**. Im a beginner at coding, its my first site and I've hosted it and its running now.

I have added the http-eqiv tag "< meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="public" >". **Thats all the work that's been done for page-caching**, I was told that was all that was needed to be done. But after running a second site audit it still says "page-caching is not enabled".

Please help me out with this guys. Ive seen a bunch of Http "tutorials" but no help really. I was hoping for step by step tutorials.

Comment: Have you set up an `.htaccess` file? If so, you’d need to put something like `ExpiresActive On`, `ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"`, etc. in it.

Comment: No I don't have that file, how do I go about setting that up?

Comment: Hm… just make an empty file, call it `.htaccess` and put it in the same directory as your website (HTML file). Then look into the above directives (`ExpiresActive` and `ExpiresByType`) to enable caching. That should actually enable caching. At least it worked for my site.

Comment: Awesome, would get back to you in a bit

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can enable caching of website content by creating an empty file, naming it `.htaccess` and moving it into the same folder as your HTML file (if you have access to your server’s FTP). Then you can write this inside it:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
```

etc. For each file type, you add a reasonable amount of time to be cached (for example a month for each picture, a day for each HTML site, etc.).

When I did this for my site, [Google PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) always pointed out the resources that were not cached yet, so it was easy to find out which lines to add.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've done as you said and copied all that into my htaccess file. I know the file works because it redirects to my www address. But the site audit I did still says it's not enabled.

Comment: What site audit are you using?

Comment: I'm using www.site-analyzer.com

Comment: Huh, that’s weird… it says it’s disabled for my site as well… well, I’m not sure what to do about it. PageSpeed Insights says all’s right.

Comment: Hmm maybe it's just a bug on site analyzer